# Addition of text to LOF makes it appear twice in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I added a quote to my list of figures using the following code, and this makes the LOF appear twice in the TOC. Does anyone know how to solve this by any chance?

[image]

```
\addtocontents{lof}{%
  \protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}%
\vspace{-2cm}
\begin{chapquote}[30pt]{Robert Heinlein}
{If it can’t be expressed in figures, it’s not science it’s opinion.}
\end{chapquote}
}
```

Comment: As always on this site, if we are suppose to help, you need to provide a full but minimal example, that shows your problem, and that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Are you sure you actually need to add `  \protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}` to the LOF like that in the first place?

Comment: As you have not provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) I have no idea what you have done in your code. For eaxmple, where does `chapquote` come from? How did youy get the LoF listed in the ToC in the first place?